# gcc - linking and compiling in one command

Tags: c++, gcc

I am new to C++ and learning RTI DDS at the moment by compiling their examples. I am currently using their make files but I want to learn how to compile individual files using gcc directly. The make files first compiles objects and links them together as per below.

```
g++ -DRTI_UNIX -DRTI_LINUX -DRTI_64BIT -m64 -O2 -o objs/x64Linux3gcc4.8.2/HelloPublisher.o  -Isrc -Isrc/idl -I/opt/rti_connext_dds-5.2.3/include -I/opt/rti_connext_dds-5.2.3/include/ndds -c src/HelloPublisher.cpp

g++ -m64 -static-libgcc -Wl,--no-as-needed objs/x64Linux3gcc4.8.2/HelloPublisher.o -o objs/x64Linux3gcc4.8.2/HelloPublisher -L/opt/rti_connext_dds-5.2.3/lib/x64Linux3gcc4.8.2 -lnddscppz -lnddscz -lnddscorez -ldl -lnsl -lm -lpthread -lrt
```

How can I write a single command using g++/gcc to do both?

Comment: Don't avoid makefiles. They *majorly* cut down on compile time. And you don't *want* to compile-and-link in a single line, since that prevents reuse of individual unchanged object files.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is

```
g++ -o $prog -DRTI_UNIX $moreflags $file1.cpp $file2.cpp $prog.cpp $libs
```

You'll have to try a bit with the myriad of arguments you got since order matters.